# ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host error with selenium on firefox

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am getting an error for the below code

**Code:**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://mycutebaby.in/contest/participant/?n=5b2b4bf83c352#_=_')
voter = driver.find_element_by_id('verification_vote_btn')
voter.click()
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hello\Documents\kritin_votes.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver.get('https://mycutebaby.in/contest/participant/?n=5b2b4bf83c352#_=_')
  File "C:\Users\Hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 332, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Users\Hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 318, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 472, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "C:\Users\Hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 496, in _request
    resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\Hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\Hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\Hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 258, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Users\Hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Comment: "forcibly closed by the remote host" makes me think you're trying to write a script to try to do multiple votes on a website, and it's detecting that you've already voted once and disconnecting.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as **Tap To Vote !** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solution:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.verification_vote-btn.vote_fb_btn#verification_vote_btn span.text"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='verification_vote-btn vote_fb_btn' and @id='verification_vote_btn']//span[contains(.,'Tap To Vote !')]"))).click()
  ```